# Insert model in world file

Tags: gazebo-7

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hey,
I have a .world file in which I have added the models.

```
<include>
      <uri>model://simple_mobile_manipulator</uri>
      <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
    </include>
```

This model is present in the models folder in .gazebo folder in home.

How to insert a model which is present in some other folder?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/21112/insert-model-in-world-file/) by [trishantroy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/7129/trishantroy/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-11-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You can set your `GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH` environment variable to include another directory containing models.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2018-11-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [trishantroy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/7129/trishantroy/) on 2018-11-19**:
Thank you!